# If else в XPATH

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, soapui

Подскажите, есть ответ, вида:

```
    <dep:deposit>
       <dep:agreementData>
          <dm:colvirReferenceId>634_24570</dm:colvirReferenceId>
          <dm:status>
             <dm:code>STCLOSEOUT</dm:code>
             <dm:name>Расторгнут досрочно</dm:name>
          </dm:status>
          <dm:code>133</dm:code>
          <dm:amount>5000</dm:amount>
          <dm:currency>RUB</dm:currency>
          <dm:documentDate>2015-12-11</dm:documentDate>
          <b:refer>3013011512126177799</b:refer>
          <b:product>
             <dm:code>3.7.1.RU</dm:code>
             <dm:name>Депозит срочный физическому лицу в национальной валюте без дополнительных взносов и частичных изъятий с капитализаций</dm:name>
          </b:product>
          <b:department>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:department>
          <b:dateFrom>2015-12-11</b:dateFrom>
          <b:dateTo>2016-12-11</b:dateTo>
          <b:deaClient>
             <dm:code>0300.000306</dm:code>
          </b:deaClient>
          <b:balanceDep>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:balanceDep>
          <b:serviceDep>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:serviceDep>
          <b:salesDep>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:salesDep>
          <b:arrestFl>0</b:arrestFl>
          <dep:depoTermTU>12.0</dep:depoTermTU>
          <dep:depoTermTimeType>M</dep:depoTermTimeType>
          <dep:lockFl>0</dep:lockFl>
       </dep:agreementData>
    </dep:deposit>
```

Где таких блоков депозитов 100+, у всех разные

```
          <dm:status>
             <dm:code>STCLOSEOUT</dm:code>
             <dm:name>Расторгнут досрочно</dm:name>
          </dm:status>
```

Как с помощью XPATH получить dm:colvirReferenceId именно с определенным кодом статуса, к примеру STCLOSEOUT.
Использовать хочу в SOAPUI test, Transfer propertis.

Буду благодарна за помощь, спасибо!